# what is the best practice of implementing a factory pattern/method in scala?

Tags: scala

I wonder what is the best practice of implementing a factory pattern/method in scala?

say we have those kind of objects:

```
case class foo1(a:Int,b:String)

case class goo1(z:Double, w:String)
```

how to create them in generic way [by maybe using a trait etc...]?

thanks

Comment: Nowhere near enough context and detail in this question. ‘Generic" in terms of what?

Comment: first best practice would be to comply with the naming convention about the classes declarations.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to write your own dependency injection module that provides instances on the fly, I'd strongly suggest that you lookup some of the existing tools. A simple google search for "Scala dependency injection frameworks" will yield many result such as `MacWire`, `Guice`,`ReaderMonad`,`cake pattern` and etc.

However my judgement aside from your motive and to simply answer the question here's **one** way you would do this in scala that also is type safe:

```scala
trait FactoryMethod[T] {
  type Args
  def defaultArgs: Args
  def withArgs(args: Args): T
  def default: T = withArgs(defaultArgs)
}

case class Foo(a:Int,b:String)
object Foo {
  implicit object factory extends FactoryMethod[Foo] {
    override type Args = (Int,String)

    override def withArgs(args: Args): Foo = (Foo.apply _).tupled(args)

    override def defaultArgs: Args = (1,"foo")
  }
}

case class Goo(z:Double, w:String)
object Goo {
  implicit object factory extends FactoryMethod[Goo] {
    override type Args = (Double,String)

    override def withArgs(args: Args): Goo = (Goo.apply _).tupled(args)

    override def defaultArgs: Args = (2L,"goo")
  }
}

object Factory {
  def of[T](implicit factory: FactoryMethod[T]): factory.Args => T = factory.withArgs
  def instanceOf[T](implicit factory: FactoryMethod[T]): T = factory.default
}

//obtain instance with default arguments
Factory.instanceOf[Goo]

//type safe way of obtaining instance with custom fed arguments
Factory.of[Foo].apply((-22,"baz"))
//By type safe I mean that the line below won't compile because the
//arguments fed for Foo are not compatible:
//Factory.of[Foo].apply(("bar","baz"))

//Note that if you abstract over the types Goo and Foo like this:
//def myMethod[T]: T = {
//  Factory.instanceOf[T]
//}
//It won't compile unless you also ask for the needed implicit
//on the method signature
def myMethod[T: FactoryMethod]: T = {
  Factory.instanceOf[T]
}
```